# Docker container with host mode not seeing /etc/hosts updates

Tags: docker

Let's say I have a host with `/etc/hosts` being:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    my_laptop
127.0.1.1    also_my_laptop
```

Let's run a container with network host:

```
docker run -it --rm --network host ubuntu
```

In this container:

- `ping also_my_laptop` will work
- `pint is_that_me` won't work

Now, while keeping this container running, modify the `/etc/hosts` on the host to:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    my_laptop
127.0.1.1    is_that_me
```

In the container, the results won't change:

- `ping also_my_laptop` will work
- `pint is_that_me` won't work

I have not found any documentation stating that these results should indeed change. But they actually do change on some other hosts, while the docker version is the same. Does anyone know:

- If the results should change ?
- Why it does or doesn't on one of my hosts ?